# How do acoustic enclosures for AC condensers work, without stopping airflow?

Tags: acoustics

How do acoustic enclosures for AC condensers like [THESE](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=acoustic%20air%20conditioning%20enclosures&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKvP6MqKXZAhXG7BQKHYFqAAIQ_AUICygC&biw=1680&bih=930) work so they allow A) airflow to / from the condensers, B) but also reduce sound output from the condensers ?

Arent (A) and (B) at odds with each other ?

Comment: They are and this article may help you understand what needs to be done. https://ac.els-cdn.com/S2351978917300604/1-s2.0-S2351978917300604-main.pdf?_tid=4f235ef8-117c-11e8-b95f-00000aacb362&acdnat=1518608803_ca47a147e45f647fdf36d81433287be0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they aren't, and here's why: an acoustic enclosure is a low-pass filter which allows free movement of extremely low frequencies (i.e., steady flow of air) into or out of the enclosure while blocking the escape of higher frequencies (motor and fan noise). This is the same job performed by the muffler on your car: it is designed so that a steady stream of exhaust gas can easily flow out of it, but the sharp impulses that contain lots of high-frequency content are blocked and internally dissipated inside the muffler.